# Change WooCommerce "Weight" attribute text label to "Shipping Weight"

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to change the label of the weight attribute in WooCommerce. By default, it shows "Weight" but I want it to display "Shipping Weight". The same for the label "Dimensions". I could use Loco Translate and make a custom translation but prefer to do it with code.

I found the following Snippet, but it does not change anything. Is it because I use the German version? I tried replacing 'weight' with 'gewicht' but it did not help.

```
function change_woocommerce_display_product_attributes_label( $product_attributes, $product ){
    if( isset( $product_attributes['weight'] ) ){
        $product_attributes['weight']['label'] = __( 'Shipping Weight', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'change_woocommerce_display_product_attributes_label', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The code work in last WooCommerce version, so the problem is maybe coming from your theme customization, a third party plugin or your own previous customizations...